# TSQL error in GROUP By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query on a populated Table variable that is supposed to return rows or each with the most recent date:

```
SELECT t.ID
    ,t.Column_2
    ,t.MaxDate AS [End Date Time]
    ,t.Column_3
    ,t.Column_4
    ,t.Column_5
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,Column_2
        ,MAX(EndDateTime) AS MaxDate
        ,Column_3
        ,Column_4
        ,Column_5
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY Column_2
    ) t
INNER JOIN @MyTable o ON t.ID = o.ID
    AND t.MaxDate = o.EndDateTime
```

I keep getting the error: `Column '@MyTable.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`  Not sure what the problem is as I'm including a GROUP BY clause in the inner select statement, do I need one outter select query as well?  Also, how can a modify this to `ORDER BY EndDateTime DESC` in the final return result??  Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:

Thank you all for your feedback, I corrected the error and learned something new.  THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all the columns that you are not aggregating. I think you should do the following:

```
SELECT o.ID
    ,o.Column_2
    ,t.MaxDate AS [End Date Time]
    ,o.Column_3
    ,o.Column_4
    ,o.Column_5
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,MAX(EndDateTime) AS MaxDate
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY ID
    ) t
INNER JOIN @MyTable o ON t.ID = o.ID
    AND t.MaxDate = o.EndDateTime
```

Comment: +1 for simplifying the posted query.  I think this is probably what he should do.

Comment: If `ID` is a key field, then `GROUP BY ID` will always select every row, making the clause pointless. The poster needs to explain what he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DourHighArch - You are right, but if `ID` is a key, then it shouldn't be on the `SELECT` when the op tries to obtain a max date.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either aggregate `MAX(), MIN(), AVG()` or `GROUP BY` **EVERY** field in the select statement.

You don't `GROUP` or aggregate `ID, Column_3 - Column_5` which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the inside-most `SELECT` query. It is telling you that you can't apply an aggregate field on one column, group by a second column, and then do nothing with the other 4. Try this instead (results may vary, depending on what you are actually trying to produce for a result):

```
SELECT t.ID
    ,t.Column_2
    ,t.MaxDate AS [End Date Time]
    ,t.Column_3
    ,t.Column_4
    ,t.Column_5
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,Column_2
        ,MAX(EndDateTime) AS MaxDate
        ,Column_3
        ,Column_4
        ,Column_5
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY ID,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4,Column_5
    ) t
INNER JOIN @MyTable o ON t.ID = o.ID
    AND t.MaxDate = o.EndDateTime
```

Answer (score -1):

When you define a group by all of the items in your select must either be included in the group by clause or included in an aggregate so the server will know what to do with the grouped values. In your inner select you would need to do something like this:

```
   SELECT ID
    ,Column_2
    ,MAX(EndDateTime) AS MaxDate
    ,Column_3
    ,Column_4
    ,Column_5
FROM @MyTable
GROUP BY ID
    ,Column_2
    ,EndDateTime
    ,Column_3
    ,Column_4
    ,Column_5
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(ID)
    ,Column_2
    ,MAX(EndDateTime) AS MaxDate
    ,SUM(Column_3)
    ,SUM(Column_4)
    ,SUM(Column_5)
FROM @MyTable
GROUP BY Column_2
```

Without providing either an aggregate or including the additional columns in the group by their behavior would be undefined.

Comment: That wasn't my downvote, but you included MAX(EndDateTime) as one of the fields in the group by

Comment: Thanks, JML. I was wondering if perhaps they had objected to the SUM(ID). Grouped aggregate removed.